# Data model for logic gates simulation

Tags: data-structures, logic

I'm tring to develop a simulator for logic gates. The simulator needs to calculate the truth table of given circuits.

Here is in an example circuit. `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e` are inputs and `z` is output.

[image]

I'm pretty new at programming. I couldn't find a way for modelling the gates. Could you advise me an approach?

Comment: This is too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  But you may well be interested in [directed graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: in simple cases without feedback chains/loops, regular trees will work well.

Answer (score 1):

For each inputs, you will need to generate the Truth Table for states (true,false). So if you have 5 inputs = total combinations = 2^5.

You did not specify what language you need this. So, I will give you a flowmatic `Java` approach.

I assume you already have all specific functions defined for the different gates such as `XNOR`, `AND`, `OR` etc. For example  you can have a function for `XNOR` gate as : `boolean XNOR(boolean ip1, boolean ip2)`

Now the process reduces to the generation of all combinations (2^5) for the inputs. This reduces to a simple permutation problem - You can do it this way: (The idea is to change the values from the end of array to the beginning. Since it takes only two values it is quite easy to implement)

```
//inputs  - all initialized to FALSE; - ready for 1st case of (2^5)
//Let the inputs a,b,c,d,e correspond to values of this array
boolean inp[]=new boolean[5]; 

//need a pointer variable for the array
//first pointing to the last-1 element of the array
int main_col=inp.length-2; 

//Generate the combinations for input from all FALSE to until you reach all inputs to TRUE values
boolean looptf=true;
while(looptf){
   call_Appropriate_gates_from_inputs(inp); 
   inp[inp.length-1]=!inp[inp.length-1]; //last array element value changed 
   call_Appropriate_gates_from_inputs(inp);
   inp[inp.length-1]=!inp[inp.length-1]; //reset
   for(int i=inp.length-2;i>=0;i--){
        if (inp[i]){
          inp[i]=false; 
          if (main_col==i){
             main_col--;
             if (main_col<0){
               looptf=false;
               break;
             }
          }           
        }else{
          inp[i]=true;
          break;
        }
    }//for        
}//while
```

Now you can define the method `call_Appropriate_gates_from_inputs(boolean[])` and execute the gate logic and get the result.